# What does click.modal.data-api as event name mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was reading through Bootstraps JavaScript and noticed the following code:

```
$(document).on('click.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function (e) {
    //do something
});
```

Can someone explain to me why it is `"click.modal.data-api"`.  What does the dot after the event do? Maybe I'm blind but I can't seem to find any documentation that talks about this.

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with selectors. The selector is the string you pass to `$` or as second argument to `.on`. In this case you are talking about the event name.

Comment: Thanks for your help Felix.I wasn't quite sure to to start but your explanation was very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a namespaced event and [the documentation *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) describes it pretty well:

> An event name can be qualified by event namespaces that simplify removing or triggering the event. For example, `"click.myPlugin.simple"` defines both the myPlugin and simple namespaces for this particular click event. A click event handler attached via that string could be removed with `.off("click.myPlugin")` or `.off("click.simple")` without disturbing other click handlers attached to the elements. Namespaces are similar to CSS classes in that they are not hierarchical; only one name needs to match. Namespaces beginning with an underscore are reserved for jQuery's use.

Answer (score 0):

It is just an event namespace. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure about this, but I think it is a sort of "personal event triggering". I explain it better: you can define your own event listeners and trigger them whenever you want. For example, you can define an event `myEvent` and trigger it just by doing `.trigger('myEvent')`. Here is a little snippet:

```
$(document).on('click.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function (e) {
    //do something
});
```

This is the declaration of the event handler, which you can trigger just by doing this:

```
$(document).trigger('click.modal.data-api');
```

Read more documentation about [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: This is actually not a custom event, since `click` is a standard event. It's a "namespaced" event.